# Strange tilde syntax

Tags: haskell

GHC accepts this code, but it ought to be illegal syntax(?) Any guesses as to what's going on?

```
module Tilde  where

~ x = x + 2             -- huh?

~ x +++ y = y * 3       -- this makes sense
```

The `(+++)` equation makes sense: it's declaring an operator, using infix syntax, and using an irrefutable pattern match on the first argument.

The first 'equation' looks like the same to start with. But there's no operator. If I ask

```
λ> :i ~
===> <interactive>:1:1: error: parse error on input `~'

λ> :i (~)
===> class (a ~ b) => (~) (a :: k) (b :: k)
     -- Defined in `Data.Type.Equality'
     instance [incoherent] forall k (a :: k) (b :: k). (a ~ b) => a ~ b
     -- Defined in `Data.Type.Equality'
```

which is a bemusing discovery, but nothing to do with it(?) I can't define my own class or operator `(~)` -- `Illegal binding of built-in syntax`, not surprisingly.

Oh:

```
λ> :i x
===> x :: Integer         -- GHCi defaulting, presumably
```

and trying to run `x` loops for ever. So the strangeness is actually defining

```
x = x + 2
```

Then what's the `~` doing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Writing

```
x = 5
```

creates a global variable named `x`, bound to the value `5`. Adding a tilde makes the pattern match irrefutable, but it was *already* irrefutable, so that doesn't make much sense. But it's legal to write something like

```
(xs, ys) = span odd [1..10]
```

This defines two global variables, `xs` and `ys`, containing all the odd numbers and all the even numbers between 1 and 10. You could even make this irrefutable if you want by adding a tilde. Of course, this pattern can't fail (if the expression is well-typed), so there's no point to that. But consider:

```
~(x:xs) = filter odd [1..10]
```

This defines two global variables, `x` and `xs`, *if* the filter returns at least one result. If the filter were to return *zero* results, the pattern match would fail. (In practice, this means that accessing `x` or `xs` would throw a pattern match failure exception.)

You can *even* write utterly bizarre stuff like

```
False = True
```

This seemingly nonsensical declaration pattern-matches the pattern `False` against the value `True`, and does nothing either way. It's one of those obscure corners of the language.

Comment: (...but top-level bindings are already irrefutable anyway, so even in your examples the `~`s are completely unnecessary.)

Comment: @DanielWagner Really? Interesting... I didn't know that.

Comment: If they weren't, at what moment should they fail? @MathematicalOrchid

Comment: @luqui When you first try to use the binding, I suppose... Hmm, but that only works if they're irrefutable... I see your point.

Comment: OK so if I want to give an equation to define `~` as a (unary, prefix) operator, that would be `(~) x = x + 2`. ;-)

Comment: @AntC have you tried it? It is part of a *syntax*. Similarly, you can't define your own function named `let`.

Comment: (1) not just top-level, `let` bindings are all irrefutable. Unless bangs `!` are involved. (2) `let False = True in False` simply returns `False` because the pattern match isn't even attempted, and if it were it'd fail. `False` isn't redefined by that as it's not a variable pattern. It's the same as `let Just x = Nothing in 1` except `False` is a nullary data constructor.

Comment: (contd.) so maybe you meant `let (2+2) = 5 in (2+2)` as the bizarre and the obscure. :)

Answer (score 10):

The tilde is doing exactly what it did in your other example: it makes the pattern irrefutable (so the pattern match can not fail). The pattern already was irrefutable, of course, in both cases (being a plain variable, which always matches), but that doesn't make the tilde illegal, just unnecessary.

Comment: Um? `x` is a niladic function, so what is (irrefutably) matching to what? I can't for example write an equivalent lambda expression.

Comment: @AntC It's not a function at all, it's an `Integer`, as you observed. You definitely can't write an equivalent lambda expression; all lambda expressions are functions. The pattern `x` matches any `Integer`, binding that `Integer` to the name `x`; so in `~x = x+2` the name `x` is bound to the expression `x+2`.

Comment: @AntC Concepts like a "niladic function" are alien to Haskell. In Haskell, all functions take exactly one argument.

Comment: @AntC `let` bindings are either pattern bindings, or function bindings (in case it's got some arguments). When there's no arguments, it's a pattern, either  simple single-variable pattern (already irrefutable), or a more complex pattern like `(a,b) = (1,2)` or `(x:xs) = [1..]` or `~(x:xs) = []`.

Comment: @AntC see [4.4.3 Function and Pattern Bindings](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-880004.5) in the report.

Comment: this is a correct answer but I think you'd agree that it's not a useful answer as it contains no explanations and no elaborations, just a cryptic determination.

Comment: @WillNess Given `~ x +++ y = y * 3       -- this makes sense`, what explanation is needed?

Comment: @DanielWagner I thought it self-evident, hmm. for instance there's more comments from you with some explanations (and whole other answer). Maybe you had only the OP in mind when answering, but there'll be many other readers too, newbies as well as the more advanced ones...